# Javascript game click events break after restarting game

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a Simon game.  It works the first time through but if I call the game.init() function to restart the game my click event for the buttons no longer works and the logic breaks (it continues to say I'm not pressing the right button in the sequence).

You can see the (semi)-working game on codepen here: http://codepen.io/cjaypierson/pen/yewjyM?editors=0010

```
var game = {
  comSeq: [],
  perSeq: [],

  init: function() {
    game.comSeq = [];
    game.perSeq = [];
    game.blinkSpace();
    game.comSelect();
    setTimeout(function() {
      game.comPlay();
    }, 1000);
    game.perSelect();
  },
  reset: function() {
    game.comSeq = [];
    game.perSeq = [];
    $('.count').text('00');
  },
  turnCount: function() {
    var l = game.comSeq.length;
    var c = l < 10 ? '0' + l : l;
    $('.count').text(c);
  },
  mistake: function() {
    $('count').text('!!');
    console.log("MISTAKE");
    setTimeout(function() {
      game.turnCount();
    }, 1500);
  },
  blinkSpace: function() {
    $('.quarter').on('mousedown mouseup', function() {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      $(this).toggleClass(id);
    })
  },
  playSound: function(id) {
    var clip = $('#' + id).find('audio');
    clip[0].play();
  },
  comSelect: function() {
    var options = ['tl', 'tr', 'br', 'bl'];
    var selection = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
    game.comSeq.push(selection);
    return selection;
  },
  comClick: function(space) {
    game.playSound(space);
    $('#' + space).toggleClass(space);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#' + space).toggleClass(space);
    }, 750);
    console.log('comSeq: ' + game.comSeq);
    console.log('perSeq: ' + game.perSeq);
  },
  comPlay: function() {
    game.perSeq = [];
    game.turnCount();
    var i = 0;
    var play = function() {
      if (i < game.comSeq.length) {
        game.comClick(game.comSeq[i]);
        i++;
        setTimeout(play, 1000);
      }
    };
    play();
  },
  perSelect: function() {
    $('.quarter').on('click', function() {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      game.playSound(id);
      game.perSeq.push(id);
      if (game.perSeq[game.perSeq.length - 1] != game.comSeq[game.perSeq.length - 1]) {
        game.mistake();
        setTimeout(function() {
          game.comPlay();
        }, 1500);
      } else {
        if (game.comSeq.length == game.perSeq.length) {
          if (game.perSeq.length >= 3) {
            $('.count').text('Winner!');
          } else {
            game.comSelect();
            setTimeout(function() {
              game.comPlay();
            }, 1500);
          }
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
$('.start').on('click', function() {
  game.init();
});
```

Comment: it seems to be working fine. I didnt understand whats happening there but I was declared as Winner.  :)

Comment: If you click start after Winning to start a new game thats when it runs into the problems.